# How can I make vim ignore the global config?

Tags: vim

I do not like the settings the sysadmin put in the system vim config file located in `/etc/vim/vimrc`.

How can I avoid loading that file and run my instances of vim with different settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out one way is to add this to my .bashrc

`alias vim='vim -U NONE -u ~/.vimrc'`

but maybe someone will come out with a better solution :)